# HTML automatically mapping href to root

Tags: c#, html

I have an anchor tag with the href set as:

```
 <a href="$myfunction(param)$">; Click Here</a>
```

When I click on Click here, it redirects to http://mywebsite/$myfunction(1234).
This page obviously does not exist. How do I ensure that clicking on the above link does not map to the root? I would like it to call the javascript function.

Note: I cannot do this:

```
<a href="javascript:$myfunction(param)$">Click Here</a>.
```

The reason is that we have a 3rd party crawler (no source code available) that searches for anchor tags on our page and picks up the href part for the link and fails if not found in the ***exact*** format $myfunction(param)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to invoke the onClick handler?

```
<a href="" onClick="myfunction(param)">; Click Here</a>
```

Another approach is the following

```js
function MyFunction(param){
 alert(param);
}
(function() {
 var aElements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 var aList = Array.prototype.slice.call(aElements);
 aList.forEach(function(elem) {   
    var regex = /\$(.*?)\$/g;
   var result =regex.exec(elem.href);
 if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
  elem.onclick= function(){
    //executes function
  eval(result[result.length-1]);
    //prevents href action;
  return false;
    }
   }
 });
})();
```

```html
<a href="$MyFunction('hello')$">I have a function</a>
<br/>
<a href="#home">I have a normal link</a>
<br/>
<a href="$MyFunction('world')$">I have another function</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately it has to be href, since the crawler only looks at href

Comment: if you add a token you can add an event listener to all your <a> elements to invoke functionality.

Just like this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/terz0sx5/

Comment: This approach will get all the  <a> elements and check if its href attribute has your custom format, if has it then will add a onclick handler dynamically to execute that command, otherwise will perform as a normal link

Answer (score 1):

HTML anchor link specification does not support adding a javascript function as the value of the href attribute. Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a you should add an URL or an URL fragment.

If you need to add it this way you can add the onclick event to anchor like this:

```
<a href="$myfunction(param)$" onclick="myfunction(param)">; Click Here</a>
```

Then you just need to make sure you function returns false and/or calls event.preventDefault this is to avoid redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onClick` event handler to call the function and prevent the default action of the link with `event.preventDefault()`.

```html
<a href="$myfunction(param)$" onclick="myfunction(event)"> Click Here</a>
<br/>
<a href="someaddress" onClick="function2()">Link that does NOT have its default action prevented</a>
<script>
function myfunction(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("Function myfunction() called");
}
function function2(){
   console.log("Function function2() called");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think, what I basically need is for the url to not be mapped to an absolute path.

Comment: @AnthonyFernandes No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'onclick' attribute of the link tag instead of href,
For example

```
<a onclick="function()">Website name</a>
```

To change the cursor and have a blue link, you may need a blank href also. Another option is to use `<input type="button" value="Name">`

`<a href onclick="function()">Button</a>`

In XHTML, it needs to have an empty string value "", or a "#"

`<a href="" onclick="function()">Button</a>`

Also, note that links or buttons that say "click here" or "here" are not descriptive. When you list the links, i.e. with a screen reader, you don't know what "here" means out of context.